# How to show/hide some alerts on a form with react hooks useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form that I want to do a basic validation check. I want to check if any of the values are empy except for the checkboxes, but we can start with just one validation. I thought I could use `useState` hook, but it always sets the default to true on first submit (when the value is filled out), even tho I am setting the value to true when the input value is filled.

```
const [nameVal, setNameVal] = useState(false);


 const submitForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();


  //console.log(e.target.name.value);

  if(e.target.name.value === ""){
    setNameVal(false);
    console.log(nameVal);
  }
  else{
    setNameVal(true);
    console.log(nameVal);
  }
```

How do I get the `console.log(nameVal)` to show `true` the first time the form is submitted and the `target.name.value` is filled out. Currently the first time it is `false` and then every time after that it is `true`. So everything seems to work as I would like except the initial click. Thanks ahead of time

Comment: you want status to be changed only one time?

Comment: keep in mind that `setXXX` from hooks will reflect the values in the next render. The `console.log(nameVal)` you're seeing, is just logging the variable `nameVal`, which is `false` at that moment

Comment: to add to Gonzalo's point, if you want the state to be based on the previous state value, pass a call back function into setXXX,  example setNameVal( prevVal => !prevVal ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's review how `useState` works

When you do this

```
const [nameVal, setNameVal] = useState(false);
```

you're creating a variable (with an initial value of false) and a function. That means that in your handler (assuming you've filled a value properly)

```
 const submitForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.target.name.value === ""){
    setNameVal(false);
    console.log(nameVal); // --> here it will log true
```

you will see logged `true`, because `nameVal` is the variable from above (from the `useState` line). When you run `setNameVal(false)` basically it continues to execute your code, and once that has finished, it fires the reconciliation algorithm in React, which will cause a new render. This time, (the second time), when this line runs

`const [nameVal, setNameVal] = useState(false);`

`nameVal` will be true. That's because the initial value *is used only on the first render.* and because *it knows the value of the state has changed, thanks to you calling the `setXXX` function to update to a new state*

You need to consider your functional components as a function of state and props, and every change for all the changes you make on your state, you will render the new output in the next render cycle. So that means - *every render has its own props and state*

(that's not mine, though, read this amazing article from Dan Abramov which also talks about useEffect https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

========================

As to your question, how to "toggle" some message to show with `useState` ? a general form could be

```
const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false)

const someEvent = () => {
  // do stuff
  if (someCondition) {
       setShowMessage(true)
  }
}

// more stuff

return (
   <div>
       { showMessage && <span>I am a message!</span>}
        <Foo onChange={someEvent} />
   </div>
)
```

Explanation:

- Initial render. `showMessage` is false, so `{ showMessage && <span>I am a message!</span>}` will return `false` (which makes React render nothing)
- When some event trigger our function handler we will set `showMessage` to true.
- On next render (the reconciliation algorithm detects a change on state and fires a new render), we see `showMessage` as true, so the `span` is rendered

Answer (score 0):

At the initial state, you have namevalue to be false, like so:

`const [nameVal, setNameVal] = useState(false);`
I'll suggest you set the new state of nameVal like so:

```
setNameVal(!nameVal);
```